# Annotate values and group by M2M field in Django

Tags: python, database, django

In the (super-simplified) code below, the function `get_top_authors()` gives me the list of authors, each with their number of published articles, sorted from the author with the most articles to the author with the fewest articles, and the function `get_articles_per_year()` gives me a list of total articles published per year for the whole database.

If I wanted the numbers of articles per year for each of the N authors (or just the top 5), I could redo the query N (or 5) times. However, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
from django.db import models

class Author:
    name = models.TextField()

class Article:
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    year = models.IntegerField()

def get_top_authors():
    top_authors = Author.objects.all() \
        .annotate(articles=models.Count('article')).order_by('-articles')

def get_articles_per_year():
    return Article.objects.all()
        .values('year').order_by('year') \
        .annotate(articles=models.Count('year'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with after some more reading:

```
articles_per_author_per_year = Article.objects.all() \
    .values('year', 'authors_name').order_by('year')\
    .annotate(articles=models.Count('id'))
```

The trick is that `annotate` after `values` aggregates over the groups formed by unique permutations of the values parameters. In this case, that means that it will add up all articles per author per year. The statement reduces to one query with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the M2M table, instead of N queries for each of the authors.